# Sync OneNote without opening the application

Tags: windows-8, sync, modern-ui, microsoft-onenote

I've been spoiled by Dropbox.  All I do is turn on my laptop and all of the offline changes I've made to documents is synchronised to the cloud.  Except for the OneNote Windows 8 app.  I have to specifically open OneNote before it will sync, presumable to perform any merges between documents.

Is there a way to enable background syncing for the OneNote Windows 8 app?

Similarly, can the same be done for OneNote 2010 beyond just leaving the app open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that even the W8 app IS actually open, just not visible.

Unfortunately not. The sync mechanism is built in to the client which has to be open.

There is a work around though. You can create notebooks anywhere including your Dropbox folders. These will be sync'd by Dropbox in the background.

The disadvantage is that you will not be able to use the native mobile clients to also edit the notebooks thus created. However, there are some third party (not free) apps that will work with Dropbox based notebooks.

Comment: This is highly not advisable as the sync is handled by dropbox and not onenote. Onenote has conflict handling mechanisms that helps to merge changes if changes occur on multiple devices.

Comment: In fact, the OneNote sync mechanism is very good (it wasn't written by Microsoft!) and is very reliable. Even working live with multiple people on Dropbox will rarely have issues. I've been using and supporting ON for quite a few years now and have notebooks on a variety of networks with no problems.